# The following commands have been executed: set 10 20 30 40 50 shift shift --- Enter the value of the variable $5:

Tags: linux

The following commands have been executed:

```
 set 10 20 30 40 50

 shift

 shift
```

Enter the value of the variable $5:

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: There is a question, not sure what it is asking. Please give more info.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pressing enter should do the trick, if it doesn't exit your client and try again.
(It must be enter only)